# Reason of "undefined" in a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out the reason why this snippet returns as undefined.

Thanks in advance

```
let x = function() {
    return
    {
        message: 'hello'
    }
}

console.log(x());
```

Comment: Because you moved `{` below `return`

Comment: Return statement terminates [at end of line](https://2ality.com/2011/05/semicolon-insertion.html).

Comment: @lucumt I fail to see how it's relevant at all.

Comment: This is called "automatic semicolon insertion", when the JS parser sees "return" and a new line character it automatically adds a semicolon, so your code becomes: "return; {...}"